# specify a custom deleter for shared_ptr but meets error

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, std, shared-ptr

I have searched in stackoverflow for how to specifiy a custom deleter for shared_ptr, and these are what I found:

```
boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr( new T, std::mem_fun_ref(&T::deleteMe) );
boost::shared_ptr<S> ptr( new S, std::ptr_fun(lib_freeXYZ) );
```

I have a class ISprite, which is abstract class with a pure virtual function destroy(), this class can create instance using libInterface->createSprite(a.bmp), now I use ISprite as a member variable in another class, would like to use shared_ptr to wrap it, but ISprite instance can't be deleted, if I have a ISprite *a, and try delete a in another class's destrcutor, system would crash, but it can use a->destroy() to release the memory,  so if I want to use shared_ptr to wrap the member variable ISprite, I need to specify my own deleter for it. and below is what I do:

```
boost::shared_ptr<ISprite> ptr(system- 
      >createSprite("a.bmp"),std::mem_fun_ref(&ISprite::destroy));
```

but the compile keep telling me 
...boost\smart_ptr\detail\shared_count.hpp(132) :

```
error C2664: 'void std::mem_fun_ref_t<_Result,_Ty>::operator ()(_Ty &) const' :         
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ISprite *' to 'ISprite &'
```

I have no idea what is wrong there, anyone could help? thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

`mem_fun_ref` expects a `T &`.  Use `mem_fun` instead; it expects a `T *`.

Comment: and one more question, my ISprite variable is a member variable in another class, so I need to initilize it in the constructor, then how can I initilize it? clearly I can't use "ptr(system-  >createSprite("a.bmp"),std::mem_fun(&ISprite::destroy));"